# Python For loop runs only once on a queryset

Tags: python, for-loop

I am having a `queryset` that returns three objects but when i run for loop on the `queryset` it runs only once.

Here is my source code:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = self.form_class(request.POST or None, assigned=self.get_form_kwargs())
    if form.is_valid():
        inputs = request.POST.getlist('input_id[]')
        pid = Model.objects.filter(id__in=inputs)
        for obj_id in pid:
            p = form.save(commit=False)
            u = Staff.objects.get(id=self.request.user.id)
            p.product = obj_id
            p.assigned_by = u
            p.save()
        return JsonResponse({'status': 'ok', 'message': 'Object Created'})
```

Any one having an idea

Comment: What ORM are you using? My guess is that the queryset object of the one you are using is not iterable and would first need to be converted to a list.

Comment: I am using django, and when i print the queryset the result is `<QuerySet [<Model: 54687>, <Model: 234365465>]>`

Comment: I dont know where i do it wrong can you figure it???? @David Jenkins

Comment: so the result is a QuerySet object, not a list, which is likely not iterable without first converting it to a list. look into the values_list method of the QuerySet object. That should get you started

Comment: I tried converting the queryset to list but still no luck, @ David Jenkins,

Comment: The problem is not the queryset, it is iterable, since you can run a for loop with it. What makes you say that the loop runs only once ?

Comment: @ David Jenkins & @ PRMoureu, i am having a form that brings the list i use to query in my model, all results come out as required through a for loop. Through the loop i want to save new objects but only the last data is saved in my model, where is my problem? i'm really stuck help plz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved the puzzle, the problem was when i run the loop it creates an object once that means i was wrong i was supposed to create an instance every time the loop runs here is my codes:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST or None, assigned=self.get_form_kwargs())
        if form.is_valid():
            for pid in request.POST.getlist('input_id[]'):
                form.save(commit=False)
                f = MyForm(request.POST, instance=MainModel(product=RelatedModel.objects.get(id=pid),
                                                               u_id=OtherModel.objects.get(id=self.request.user.id)),
                                             assigned=self.get_form_kwargs())
                f.save()

            return JsonResponse({'status': 'ok', 'message': 'Handover Created'})
```

Comment: This runs the queryset's `get` inside the loop, which means it will go to the database if there's no caching. Now Django is smart and it will cache DB queries, but you should not rely on that. As someone already mentioned, just assign it into a list and use from that multiple times. eg. `my_objects = list(Model.objects.get())`

Comment: @tayfun i've assigned it to list, and it works fine, thanks for the idea